# Going through 2D array

Tags: shell-script, array, dash

I have an expression

```
ls -l `find . -type f` | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | sort | uniq -c  | tr -s [:space:] | sort -k 2n
```

which creates a 2D array like:

```
 xx yy
 xx yy
 xx yy
```

where xx is numerosity of incidence and yy is the size of the files with incidence xx. What i need is to compare every cell yy with some numbers (like if (yy <  100 B) .. if(yy < kiB) .. etc.) and according to this print '#' xx times to the right row in table. 
I was trying

```
awk '{print $1;}'
```

but it just takes one column and I can´t specify row like in C for example.
Is it somehow possible to do it? it must work on dash, ksh and bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each block in `awk` you can put a condition that must be met.

```
awk '$2 < 100 {for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) printf "#"; next;}
     $2 < 500 {for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) printf "x"; next;}
     ...'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, although I must repeatly call the expression but it isn´t such a big problem